# R: How do I add a column to a dataframe based on paired values in another dataframe with different length?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyverse

In R, I have unsuccessfully tried to merge to dataframes of different length which are matched by a column called id. Do anyone know how to address this?

Input:

df1:

```
id  group
1   x
2   y
3   x
```

df2:

```
id  day
1   0   
1   1   
1   2
2   0 
2   1
2   2
3   0 
3   1
3   2
```

Desired output (df2 with an added group column based on df1):

```
id  day   group
1   0     x
1   1     x
1   2     x
2   0     y
2   1     y
2   2     y
3   0     x
3   1     x
3   2     x
```

Comment: have you simply tried `merge(df1, df2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using left_join from dplyr package:

library(dplyr)

data <- left_join(df1,df2, by="id")

Answer (score 1):

Use a left_join

```
library(dplyr)
df_joined<- df2 %>%
   left_join(df1, by="id")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple merge function with specification of "id" variable works well

```
merge(df1,df2,by="id")
```